# Reset a form after sending - Spring-MVC

Tags: html, spring-mvc

When i fill then send a **form:form** the values are sent and i can't initialize the form even by the reset button. and I'm always compelled to make it empty manually.

How can I resolve this problem please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution, for example this is our form :

```
<form:form action="/add" commandName="cmd" method="get">
```

The controller must be defined like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String AddActivity(@ModelAttribute BeanClass cmd ,ModelMap model){
       //Here we have operations we want to do with this cmd
           // Add an empty cmd to the controller at the end
           model.addAttribute("cmd",new BeanClass);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not know much about mvc but you should be able to reset the form with a button in html. Include the following inside your form.

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset!">
```

Comment: If this does not work please submit your code so we can better help you.

Comment: I tried the reset button it's not working because the form is linked to the ModelAttribute. However, I find an astuce to resolve the problem is to add a new ModelAttribute to the page by the controller after sending.